# how to fetch same record multiple time based on date conditions in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Table structure like

```
id  p_id    payout_date 
1   2       2018-04-21
```

MY SELECT QUERIES IS

```
SELECT * 
FROM `payout` 
where payout_date >='2018-04-20' or DATE_ADD(`payout_date`, INTERVAL 30 DAY) >='2018-05-20'
```

i need result  like

```
id   p_id    date
1    2       2018-04-21
1    2       2018-05-20
```

Comment: You have one record as input and two as output. How do you explain this?

Comment: You want to generate a row a month on from the existing last payout_date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear on how your data hangs together but a union might do.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int, p_id int,   payout_date date);
insert into t values
(1  , 2 ,      '2018-04-21');

select id,p_id,payout_date 
from t 
union
select id,p_id,date_add(payout_date,interval 1 month)
from t;

+------+------+-------------+
| id   | p_id | payout_date |
+------+------+-------------+
|    1 |    2 | 2018-04-21  |
|    1 |    2 | 2018-05-21  |
+------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```